# Run fetchmail at login under MacOSX

Tags: macos, fetchmail

I'm using MacOSX and I'm trying to migrate to `mutt` and `fetchmail` because `Mail.app` started giving me several issues.

My configuration sits on`~/.fetchmailrc`and I launch the daemon issuing `fetchmail -d 600`. I tried to write a `launchd` file to handle the task at login, but doesn't work, here's the plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>org.atma.fetchmail</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
      <string>/opt/local/bin/fetchmail</string>
      <string>-f /Users/atma/.fetchmailrc</string>
      <string>-d 600</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
  <string>atma</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I think the problem is the user `env` variables. Tried using a wrapper bust still nothing. I have another `plist` provided by MacPorts which ignites a global configuration file located in `/opt/local/etc/.fetchmailrc`. But I'm afraid that using a global configuration might mess my current setup.

Any way I can adjust he above `plist` to run successfully?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the ProgamArguments furter down. AFAIK there has to be NO unescaped whitespace inside the single Strings.

Comment: Didn't need to, solved it using a different approach. Fetchmail comes with a 'global plist' on macports. I just pass the mail to maildrop configuring globally using `/opt/port/etc/fetchmailrc` and then maildrop the `$HOME/.mailfilter` for each user. Works great.